# How to calculate the minimum of a measure?

Tags: dax

How to calculate the minimum of a measure?

I have this Field Parameter with meaures:

```
NetSales = SUM('Table'[SalesValue])

SalesQty = SUM('Table'[Quantity])
```

Table is like:

Customer ID | Quantity | SalesValue

I want the minimum value of Quantity and Sales value per customer id.

So, using the NetSales in a slicer (single selection), the following expression:

```
MinNetSales = MINX('Table', SELECTEDMEASURE())
```

Which is returning **BLANK**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECTEDMEASURE() works with **Calculation Groups** only.
With **Field Parameters** you can use the following workaround:

```
MinMeasure = 
    SWITCH(
        SELECTEDVALUE(Parameter[Parameter Fields]),
        "'Table'[NetSales]", Min('Table'[SalesValue]),
        "'Table'[SalesQty]", Min('Table'[Quantity])
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, interesting workaround!

Comment: ERROR: Column [Parameter] is part of composite key, but not all columns of the composite key are included in the expresion or its dependent expression.

Comment: You should've provided sample data to make your problem reproducible.